# Nuxt: Proxy VS Async data VS Reload page

Tags: proxy, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I am building a nuxt application and I am facing an issue with Proxy and Async data.

This is my **nuxt.config**  (simplified)

```
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'@nuxtjs/proxy'
],
axios: {
  proxy: true
},
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://www.example.com',
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api': '/'
    }
  }
}
```

This is my **asyncData** code fragment (simplified):

```
async asyncData ({ store }) {
  await store.dispatch('fetchData')
}
```

Store action **fetchData** code (simplified):

```
async fetchData({ commit }) {
    const response = await myService.fetchData()
    commit('setData', response.data)
}
```

And at last, **myService** function (simplified):

```
fetchData () {
    return axios.get('/api/path-to-my-resource')
}
```

**What is expected:**
To have the service triggering a call to the proxied endpoint, on both cases: visiting the page through a link or refreshing the page

**What is happening:**
When I hit refresh on the page, instead of firing a call to the **http://www.example.com/path-to-my-resource**, I see that it tries to do it at **/api/path/to-my-resource** and of course it fails. From what I understand, when I refresh the page, the proxy is not working inside the asyncData hook.

I am pretty sure that there is something that I attempt wrongly, but I cannot find it. Can someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue when using server-side hooks (i.e. asyncData, created etc.). Server tries to connect to `127.0.0.1/...` instead of proxy `target` and gets `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: yes. the issue was that using the proxy, you edit the axios instance of nuxt. by using `import axios from 'axios` at the start of your store or service, you practically use another instance of axios, which is not configured with the proxy.

so what I did, is that I removed the service, moved all the endpoint calls inside my store, and used everywhere `this.$axios.xxxx`, so that I use the proxy everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```js
proxy: {
  '/api/': { target: 'http://www.example.com', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} }
// ^^^^^                                                      ^^^^^^   ^^
// Note the ending slashes.
// And the rewrite rule.
}
```

That's how the docs are written:

- http (`ky`) module: https://http.nuxtjs.org/api/#proxy
- Axios module: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#proxy

Comment: Even though that was not the solution to my problem, you gave me the right idea. Indeed, it was a matter of slashes in the urls while calling the endpoint in my service. But since YOU gave me the idea, there you go. Here's my upvote.

Comment: @PanosVakalopoulos I am having the exact same issue you were having. My nuxt.config file is setup exactly like the accepted answer, but the proxy is still failing on page refresh. Do you end up doing something different?

Comment: hi @Lateralus, please check my comment on the question section. it seems that the issue was that I configuring different instances of axios. you have to use the nuxt's axios instance all the time, because THAT is the instance that you have configured