# @Nuxtjs/proxy module path not rewriting on page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am working on a nuxt application which uses `axios` to get data from an API on the backend using `asyncData`. I also have the `@nuxtjs/proxy` module added as a dependency which proxies all of my API calls.

Whenever I navigate to the page using a link on the client side, the proxy works as intended and removes the `/api/` prefix from the path before sending the request to the backend API.

> Example:
>
> 1. Client requests: `/api/data`
> 2. Proxy strips `/api/` from request
> 3. Resulting path to api: `http://example.com/data`

However, the issue I am running into is on page refreshes. The proxy module is failing to strip `/api/` from the path resulting in a path that does not exist on the api

> Example:
>
> - Desired path: `http://example.com/data`
> - Path on refresh: `http://example.com/api/data`

Here is my simplified `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  components: true,
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: process.env.API_URL, pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' } },
  }
}
```

Here is a simplified verson of my `.Vue` page:

```html
<template>
  <div>This is a vue Page</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VuePage',
  async asyncData({ error, query, $axios }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await $axios.get('/api/data', { params: query });
      return {
        data,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      error({
        statusCode: err.response.status,
        message: err.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

I have already checked out some other question on StackOverflow with no good solid answer.

A similar question asked was, [Nuxt: Proxy VS Async data VS Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822969/nuxt-proxy-vs-async-data-vs-reload-page)

The question was marked as answered with no explanation given of the how the problem was solved.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I was able to find a workaround and post my solution as an answer below. Please let me know if this works for you. @Riku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround in the form of a plugin that appears to resolve the issue.

The plugin is based off a reddit post by user `wiked03` and is designed to strip `/api/` from the request

#### Create the plugin

Create a folder in your project root called `plugins` and create a file called `axios.js`

Add this code to `./plugins/axios.js`

```js
// ./plugins/axios.js

export default function ({ $axios }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    if (process.server) {
      config.url = config.url.replace('/api/', process.env.API_URL)
    }
  })
}
```

#### Configure NUXT to use the Axios plugin

Locate your your nuxt config file `nuxt.config.js` and edit it as follows:

```js
// ./nuxt.config.js

export default {
  // ~~~~ Some Configs ~~~~ //
  plugins: ['~/plugins/axios.js'],
}
```

Source:

- [Reddit Post - wiked03](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/kludco/comment/gheesr1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)